# Electrolysis of brine with filter paper bridge

Tags: electrolysis

[image: Electrolysis of brine practical]

What would be the problem with connecting the two dishes up with a piece of metal wire?

Comment: You would have electrolysis running on both ends of that wire. Other than that, no problem.

Comment: That's a bit of an understatement, @IvanNeretin. Depending on the wire material, one end would be gone within short time, OR you get electrolysis also there, and why then split the thing into two dishes in the first place? You also need twice the voltage (or a bit less, if the wire dissolves). Question to OP: What is that thing supposed to do? Why two dishes?

Comment: If  the purpose is to electrolytically seperate a salt, then you need move ions from one cell to the other. The purpose of the bridge is to transport those ions. Solid metal will conduct electrons but not ions. In the past mercury (liquid) was used industrially to transport sodium ions from one cell to the other, but its is too toxic and contaminates the fluids in the sodium hydroxide, and brine cells.